# Filtering a list of strings using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, list, filter

I have a list of strings that looks like this,

```
strlist = [
            'list/category/22',
            'list/category/22561',
            'list/category/3361b',
            'list/category/22?=1512',
            'list/category/216?=591jf1!',
            'list/other/1671',
            'list/1y9jj9/1yj32y',
            'list/category/91121/91251',
            'list/category/0027',
]
```

I want to use regex to find the strings in this list, that contain the following string `/list/category/` followed by an integer of any length, but that's it, it cannot contain any letters or symbols after that.

So in my example, the output should look like this

```
list/category/22
list/category/22561
list/category/0027
```

I used the following code:

```
newlist = []
for i in strlist:
    if re.match('list/category/[0-9]+[0-9]',i):
        newlist.append(i)
        print(i)
```

but this is my output:

```
list/category/22
list/category/22561
list/category/3361b
list/category/22?=1512
list/category/216?=591jf1!
list/category/91121/91251
list/category/0027
```

How do I fix my regex? And also is there a way to do this in one line using a filter or match command instead of a for loop?

Comment: perfect!, can it be done in a single line?

Comment: i mean like instead of a for loop

Comment: You can use list comprehension if you want this done in a single line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below regex:

```
^list\/category\/\d+$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`^`** - Represents the start of the given test String.
>
> **`\d+`** - Matches digits that occur one or more times.
>
> **$** - Matches the end of the test string. **This is the part your regex missed**.

Demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/OZNkWX/2)

**IMPLEMENTATION IN PYTHON**

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"^list\/category\/\d+$", re.MULTILINE)
match = pattern.findall("list/category/22\n"
               "list/category/22561\n"
               "list/category/3361b\n"
               "list/category/22?=1512\n"
               "list/category/216?=591jf1!\n"
               "list/other/1671\n"
               "list/1y9jj9/1yj32y\n"
               "list/category/91121/91251\n"
               "list/category/0027") 
print (match)
```

You can find the sample run of the above implementation [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/Sk5XeB5oU)